# how are large quantities of css templates produced?

Tags: css, templates

After browsing css templates in html5up.net, I am really curious as to how design sites/companies produce all their templates. With the amount they churn out, they would surely have to have some sort of efficient system. At first I was thinking that experienced designers might have a combination of  coding by hand and copy/pasting large chunks from old templates to new ones. Basing new templates loosely off another in this way would yield some sort of speedy production... Then I thought, with how well organized the front end files are, they can't be coded by hand (or at least not most of it) - it would make sense that they are made from programming that generate the templates, sort of like a template for building templates. I would only go so far as to speculate the possibility, but I would like to know how a person churn out the templates like that. If this isn't the case, is it feasible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be accomplished with preprocessed CSS.

At the simplest level, these languages/frameworks can be viewed as allowing substantial amounts of CSS to be output by making changes to core template files- through the use of variables, mixins, nesting and formulaic derivation / inline functions. Once the templates are set up, something like, say a site colour change, can be accomplished by only changing one or two variables.

You may want to look at [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) ([wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sass_%28stylesheet_language%29), [article](http://www.metaltoad.com/blog/what-sass))

> Sass is a scripting language that is interpreted into Cascading Style
>   Sheets (CSS). SassScript is the scripting language itself. Sass
>   consists of two syntaxes. The original syntax, called "the indented
>   syntax" uses a syntax similar to Haml. It uses indentation to
>   separate code blocks and newline characters to separate rules. The
>   newer syntax, "SCSS", uses block formatting like that of CSS. It uses
>   braces to denote code blocks and semicolons to separate lines within a
>   block. The indented syntax and SCSS files are traditionally given the
>   extensions .sass and .scss respectively.

There's also [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) ([wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LESS_%28stylesheet_language%29)) which works in a similar way.

> LESS (Leaner CSS) is a dynamic stylesheet language designed by Alexis
>   Sellier. It is influenced by Sass and has influenced the newer "SCSS"
>   syntax of Sass, which adapted its CSS-like block formatting syntax.
>   LESS is open-source. Its first version was written in Ruby, however in
>   the later versions, use of Ruby has been deprecated and replaced by
>   JavaScript. The indented syntax of LESS is a nested metalanguage, as
>   valid CSS is valid LESS code with the same semantics. LESS provides
>   the following mechanisms: variables, nesting, mixins, operators and
>   functions; the main difference between LESS and other CSS precompilers
>   being that LESS allows real-time compilation via LESS.js by the
>   browser. LESS can run on the client-side and server-side, or
>   can be compiled into plain CSS.

Finally there's [stylus](http://learnboost.github.io/stylus/) ([wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stylus_%28stylesheet_language%29))

> Stylus is a dynamic stylesheet language designed influenced by Sass
>   and LESS. It's regarded as the third most used CSS preprocessor
>   syntax.